# Using jQuery, how do I select elements that are neither class A nor B?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

If I have a list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="A"></li>
    <li class="A B"></li>
    <li class="A C"></li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery, how would I select only the first item, but not the other two? In other words, how do I write a selector that will **only** select an element that does not have class B or C?

Comment: Everyone wrote the same thing. Which one do I pick as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the `:not()` selector or `.not()` method:

```
$('.a').not('.b, .c')

$('.a:not(.b,.c)')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('li.A:not(.B,.C)')
```

- the [`element-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)
- the [`class-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)
- the [`not-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)
- the [`multiple-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    $(".a").not('.b, .c').text('aaa');
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bitsmix/h2fpq/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .not() method:

```
$('li.a').not('.b, .c')
```